# Put React application inside another application

Tags: reactjs, react-router

For react application I have to build sidebar menu and appropriate content on right side with dynamic content through navigation. This part is completed and now there are more menus in sidebar in existing application which are developed in different language and that should also be seen exactly like same sidebar and redirect to appropriate pages.

Block 1 will have only my react's application and block 2 can be page from react app or another app according to the navigation from sidemenu. 
How can I achieve this?

[image: Application]

Comment: not sure if it helps but I can mention [StoryBook](https://storybook.js.org)

Comment: My question is like I have existing system and I'm building a part of app in React and other part i want to be working same as it is right now. Does this relate to this story book?

Comment: You could use and [iFrame](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp) if you're trying to display content from another site. It's not clear where your "other application" is coming from though. Can you just create another Component within your React app to render the content you need?

Comment: Very interesting case, I'm planning to realize the same solution in some perspective and got some articles to read - [this](https://medium.com/@areai51/building-microfrontends-with-react-node-part-1-cf88643b9a4c) and [this](https://medium.com/@sumn2u/merging-different-isolated-react-apps-into-single-app-e2158d19868d) for the beginning.

Comment: @jpetty yes, i could use iframes, in that case how can i use authentication? 
And another application is coming from jsp - server side rendering

Comment: @lazy.lizard Thanks for the articles, will sure look at it.